# How to find inner angles and side of the rhombus given height and diagonal AC

Tags: quadrilateral

I have to find inner angles $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\delta$ and $\gamma$, other diagonal $\left|BD\right|$ and length of a side $a$ into a rhombus where is given the height $h = 2\sqrt{3} cm$ and the diagonal $\left|AC\right| = 4\sqrt{3} cm$.

How would I find this? :D Can you help me somebody? :)

I tried with $\sin{\alpha} = \frac{h}{a}$, but I still haven't found the solution. Somebody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

note that

$$
\sin (\angle ACD)=\frac{h}{\overline{AC}}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

From this you can find the side an the other diagonal of the rhombus.

[image]

Comment: Emilio, is $\triangle{ACD}$ right triangle that you can use $\sin{\angle ACD}$? :D I have [link](http://shrani.najdi.si/?22/3p/3OjcX0LT/romb.png)picture[/link] of a rhombus and I don't see $\triangle ACD$ is right triangle?

Comment: No, $ACD$ is not a right triangle. But, if $AH=h$ is the height of the rhombus from $A$ to the side $CD$, than $ACH$ is a right triangle and $\angle ACH=\angle ACD$.

Comment: [link](http://shrani.najdi.si/?22/3p/3OjcX0LT/romb.png)picture of my rhombus[/link] ... Can you upload your image? :D

Comment: I have added a figure. It's essentially the same as your.

Comment: Cool, cool. ;) Thanks. I figure it out. ;)